Zebra ZQ620 can not find service from Chrome bluetooth
I want to connection ZQ620(this is verification machine) and print, use bluetooth from Android Chrome browser JavaScript (pure or jQuery) only.
Find device is ok but service is not find error occurred.
My source is this.
const DEVICE_UUID = '0000fe79-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb';
const SERVICE_UUID = '38eb4a84-c570-11e3-9507-0002a5d5c51b';
var printer = null;
var printRes = null;
function sendText(s) {
    let encoder = new TextEncoder("utf-8");
    let txt     = encoder.encode(s+ '\u000A\u000D\u000A\u000D\u000A\u000D\u000A\u000D\u000A\u000D');
    return printer.writeValue(txt);
}
function fnc(eve){
    navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
        filters: [{
            namePrefix: 'X',
        }],
        optionalServices: [SERVICE_UUID]
    })
    .then(device => {
        console.log('connect device start');
        return device.gatt.connect();
    })
    .then(server => {
        console.log('start primary servicies');
        //return server.getPrimaryService(SERVICE_UUID);
        return server.getPrimaryServices();  //throw error
    })
    .then(services => {
        console.log(services);
    })/*
    .then(service => {
        console.log('start characteristic');
        return service.getCharacteristic(SERVICE_UUID);
    })
    .then(characteristic => {
        printer = characteristic;
        printRes = sendText($("#_textarea").val());
    })*/
    .catch(error => {
        console.err('error occurred', error);
    })
}

But, error occurrd. Throws error is 'NotFoundError: No Services found in device.' from 'return server.getPrimaryServices();'
nRF Connect app said service is exist, but can not access(screeenshot).

So, how connect and print? This printer not supported? Can I use it on other devices?
I'm sorry if my English is strange.

Apart from the fact that the ServiceUUID is clearly 38eb4a80-c570-11e3-9507-0002a5d5c51b and not 38eb4a84-c570-11e3-9507-0002a5d5c51b, have you asked ZEBRA for help?

I sent Zebra forum but not sent e-mail(Can I sent develop help mail?).
